# fwrite in C giving different values in output files

Tags: c, fwrite, c-strings

why are the output files different when I use fwrite in another function VERSUS fwrite in the same function?

output1.txt contains garbage value like Ê, which is NOT correct

output2.txt contains "b", which is correct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void writeData(char *buf, char *path) {
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen(path, "a");
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp1);
}

int main () {


    char buf[2] = "a";
    char buf2[3] = "yb";
    char file1_path[12] = "output1.txt";
    char file2_path[12] = "output2.txt";
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    memcpy(buf, &buf2[1], strlen(buf2));
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    writeData(buf, file1_path);

    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen(file2_path, "a");
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp2);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Inside `writeData()` the expression `&buf` points to a pointer, not the buffer.

Comment: In `main`, `&buf` is wrong as well, the compiler should warn about wrong type! Works because with an array, the *addresses* `buf` and `&buf` are same (but not the types)

Comment: And do close your file, it might give you unexpected output.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - `fwrite()` takes a `void*` for the first argument. It doesn't much care about the type of the pointer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ok, still it looks like a typical error you also see with `fputs()` for exanple. `&buf` definitely isn't what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `writeData` function, in your call to `fwrite`:

```
fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp1);
```

the variable `buf` is a pointer to the first character in the string to write. It's of type`char *`. However the expression `&buf` is a pointer to the variable `buf`, its type is `char **`. It's not the same data.

---

It works if `buf` is an *array* because both then `buf` (which is really `&buf[0]`) and `&buf` points to the same location. They are still different types though.

For example with

```
char buf[2];
```

then `buf` *decays* to a pointer to the arrays first element (i.e. `&buf[0]`) and is of type `char *`. The expression `&buf` is a pointer *to the array* and is of type `char (*)[2]`.

Somewhat graphically

```
+--------+--------+
| buf[0] | buf[1] |
+--------+--------+
^
|
&buf[0]
|
&buf
```

Two pointers to the same location, but different types and different semantic meanings.

Answer (score 2):

In function writeData change

```
fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp1);
```

to

```
fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fp1);
```

Answer (score 1):

writeData() should call fwrite(buf, ...) not fwrite(&buf, ...)